# Redirect IP-packets to my Application and then send them forward

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, iptables

I want to process IP-packets in my app like encrypting them, remove "bad" ones etc if they match some rule (say for example destination ip) and then send to destination. I think I can use for that purpose REDIRECT of iptables. I know that after forwarding packets to my app the original destination address will be overwritten but there is a solution:

> iptables overrites the original destination address but it remembers
>   the old one. The application code can then fetch it by asking for a
>   special socket option, SO_ORIGINAL_DST
>
> ```
> static int getdestaddr_iptables(int fd, const struct sockaddr_in *client, const struct sockaddr_in *bindaddr, struct sockaddr_in *destaddr)
> {
>         socklen_t socklen = sizeof(*destaddr);
>         int error;
>
>         error = getsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, destaddr, &socklen);
>         if (error) {
>                 log_errno(LOG_WARNING, "getsockopt");
>                 return -1;
>         }
>         return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> solution taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166692/how-does-a-transparent-socks-proxy-know-which-destination-ip-to-use)

For this purpose I also configured IPv4 forwarding by doing this:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

But then by trying to set iptable's rule, I've got an error

My rule is: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p ip -j REDIRECT --to-port 666`

Error: `iptables v1.4.21: Need TCP, UDP, SCTP or DCCP with port specification1`

I'm really newbie in iptables and in such theme in general. Can somebody tell me what I doing wrong? Why it can't do redirect with IP? And is my idea correct? I know also about divert-sockets, but they don't support fragmentation.

UPD1 Let me get straight about my problem: I want my device which is connected to internet be kind of gateway for incoming/outgoing connections. And I want to process those packets with help of my app. Some packets I will modify if they match some rule, other - just send forward without any modifications. And the laptop is "getting the internet" with help of that device

Comment: It seems you are trying to reinvent iptables or a firewall. Why don't you implement your app logic as iptables rules?

Comment: Yes, I can handle those packets with help of iptables rules, I understand this. But as I said, I need to modify some of the packets and this is impossible with iptables (encrypt payloads, change src/dst IP etc). That's why I need to do what I want.

Comment: That sounds like a rule for the `mangle` table actually.

Comment: But with mangle table I'm only can change TOS, TTL, MARK, SECMARK and CONNSECMARK, but not the payloads.

Answer (score 1):

The IP protocol simply does not have port numbers. TCP and UDP both offer 65536 ports, but these are unrelated. One is a 2 byte field in the TCP header, the other is a 2 byte field in the UDP header. ICMP (ping) does not have ports at all.

Comment: Oops, I missed that moment, maybe because I'm very tired. Thanks. I've posted additional information about the "problem"